# How to mark and delete some or all contacts?

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I've accidentally "imported contacts from storage" and now all my Gmail contacts I've ever emailed to are in my contacts on my phone! Now I can't find any option to be able to get rid of them, "export from storage" doesn't work as expected. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Since it doesn't look like a feature that Android natively supports, you can try [Contact Remover](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.octabode.dcfd&hl=en); it lets you to mark the contacts you want to delete.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it says "This app is incompatible with your Samsung Galaxy Nexus."

Comment: Try a similar app like [Mass contact Delete](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.probosoft.masscontactsdelete&hl=en)